# How to select dynamically linked items from Pricing Matrix via PHP REST API

Tags: rest-api, php, pricebook

I've been given the task of writing a new SalesForce application for our company. It's to be a sort of front-end for some clients. One of the functions is to allow these clients to build a product with a variety of items in the Pricing Matrix.
Until now, our sales reps have been doing this. Each rep has a couple of spread sheets that tells them which frame can go with what display sizes, and what displays can go with what controllers, etc. So the sales reps know what items will build together and what items are incompatible. Here comes the problem, now that we're putting the construction of the product in the hands of the clients and partners(for the purpose of acquiring a quotes more efficiently), we need SalesForce to be able to handle the dynamic linking and filtering among all of the Pricing Matrix items. So if the partner or client selects Frame_998 they won't see Display_7 or Display_44, but they will see Display_2 and Display_39 ... and on and on all the way down the ladder until the entire product has been designed. There are also combinatorial selections as well. For instance, if item_3 has been paired with item_89 - then and only then will item_66 be available for selection. After the product has been "built" by the client or partner, it will be submitted to Opportunities for processing and quote generation.
So, there's my question. Can SF handle this type of dynamic Pricing Matrix item relationship linking? If so, can I access this from the REST API? and - if so - how?
Thanks :)